# Iterate through input of type="number" in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <table id="Container1Details" cellspacing="15">


    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"> 
                <input name="acidity" type="number" maxlength="4" id="acidity" min="0.112" max="0.152" step="0.001" style="width:108px" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="h3"> Soda</span>
                <select name="h2O2Test" id="h2O2Test" allow-empty="true">
                    <option value="">NOT TESTED</option>
                    <option value="N">NEGITIVE</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"> 
                <input name="lacticTest" type="number" maxlength="2" id="lacticTest" min="1" max="20" step="1" style="width:108px" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td align='left'>
                <input  name="orderId" size="10pt" type="text" id="orderId"  autocomplete="off"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Is there a possibility to iterate though all the inputs of type="number" and assign values to them. I am easily able to iterate through inputs of type="text" and type="select" by using something like `.find(':text,:file').each(function() {});`

Comment: [jQuery Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: use $('input[type="number"]').each(function(){

})

Comment: Why would you not simply use `$('input')`, which would select all `<input>` elements regardless of their type attribute?

Comment: @DavidThomas There is also `type="text"` apparently.

Comment: @VisionN: indeed, but since he's already selecting those - and the question gives no explanation as to whether he wants to select the number-inputs *as well* (in the same selector) or separately (with a new selector and chained methods) - I thought it worth asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, just use selector `type` to do the same thing with type `number`:

```
$('input[type="number"]').each(function(){
    //Assign values HERE
    $(this).val('value');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Changed so much now I'm confused

Comment: Okay i see it should be `$(this).val('value');` no ?.

Comment: @Pogrindis He either.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki To change the element's value you should use either `this.value = 'value';` or `$(this).val('value');`. If you try to set `$(this).val = 'value';` you will just assign string value to a functional property of `$(this)` jQuery object.

Comment: Yes that true, :( i'm sorry, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it appears you want to select all `<input>` elements regardless of their type-attribute; which would lead me to suggest:

```
// selects all <input> elements, and uses the val() method
// to iterate over the returned elements:
$('input').val(function (index, currentValue) {

    // the switch retrieves the type property-value
    // of the current node:
    switch (this.type) {

        // and if it's equal to 'number':
        case 'number':

            // we return the average between the max and min values:
            return (parseFloat(this.max) + parseFloat(this.min)) / 2;
            break;

        // if it's of type equal to 'text':
        case 'text':

            // we return the string of 'appropriateValue':
            return 'appropriateValue';
            break;
    }
});
```

```js
$('input').val(function(index, currentValue) {

  switch (this.type) {
    case 'number':
      return (parseFloat(this.max) + parseFloat(this.min)) / 2;
      break;
    case 'text':
      return 'appropriateValue';
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Container1Details" cellspacing="15">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input name="acidity" type="number" maxlength="4" id="acidity" min="0.112" max="0.152" step="0.001" style="width:108px" required / </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"> <span class="h3"> Soda</span>

        <select name="h2O2Test" id="h2O2Test" allow-empty="true">
          <option value="">NOT TESTED</option>
          <option value="N">NEGITIVE</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input name="lacticTest" type="number" maxlength="2" id="lacticTest" min="1" max="20" step="1" style="width:108px" required="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align='left'>
        <input name="orderId" size="10pt" type="text" id="orderId" autocomplete="off" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ty7t8Lxx/).

To focus on only those `<input>` elements whose `type` is of `number`, then:

```
$('input[type=number]').val(function (index, currentValue) {

    // sets the new value of each number-<input> to the
    // result of the parsed current-value multiplied by
    // the index of the current element in the collection
    // returned by the selector:
    return parseInt(currentValue, 10) * index;
});
```

Comment: I am iterating through each input type separately. May be I can use this for better readability. I will try. Thank u.